# Зачем нужна решетка в этом запросе и чем первый action отличается от второго?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Не силен в thymeleaf. Не могу понять смысл этой строки:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${com.example.sweater.domain.Person}" method="post">
```

Comment: Это обычный якорь.- закладка с уникальным именем на определенном месте веб-страницы, предназначенная для создания перехода к ней по ссылке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для правильности написания `<form>` нужно указывать `action` атрибут. Значение решетка означает текущий фрагмент URL, который указывает на текущую страницу.

Второй `th:action` вычисляет выражение указанное в значении и создает/меняет значение `action` аттрибута формы.

Если по каким либо причинам выражение не вернет URL для акшен атрибута, то форма не будет отправляться, так как есть `action` аттрибут, который указывает на текущую страницу. При этом значение фрагмента `#` предохраняет страницу от рефреша. В данном случае абсолютно бесполезный, но возможно есть обработчик на JS.