# Почему Firefox отправляет заново информацию после выполнения post запроса

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Ошибка:**

> To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier

**Вот перевод:**

> Чтобы отобразить эту страницу, Firefox должен отправить информацию, которая будет повторять любое действие (например, поиск или подтверждение заказа), выполненное ранее.

Такая ошибка возникла при разработке сайта с использованием `Thymeleaf` и `Java 21`.
Возникла при добавлении к тэгу HTML `type="submit"` (`<button type="submit" class="button">`) или из-за чего-то другого. Почему она возникла?

Прилагаю вероятный код, из-за которого и возникла эта ошибка... может быть. Заранее вас благодарю за ответы!

**Контроллер:**

```
@PostMapping
    public String commentAdd(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String text, Model model) {
        Comment comment = new Comment(name, text);
        commentRepository.save(comment);
        return "index";
    }
```

Сам **html-документ** (не весь естественно):

```
<div class="container-comment">
        <div class="comment">
            <form class="comment-input-button" method="post">
                <div class="comment-input">
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="Имя">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <textarea name="text" class="text" placeholder="Текст"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="button">
                    ДОБАВИТЬ
                </button>
            </form>
            <div class="comments" th:each="comment : ${comments}">
                <div th:text="${comment.username}" class="name_user"></div>
                <div th:text="${comment.text}" class="text_user"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871705/to-display-this-page-firefox-must-send-information-that-will-repeat-any-action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, точно на тэге `<form>` нужно ставить атрибут `th:action`, чтобы было видно куда отправляется post запрос. А ошибка возникает потому что страница перегружается после отправки формы на сервер.

Вот правильный ответ:

> Это происходит, когда вы обновляете страницу, являющуюся результатом запроса POST (а не запроса GET).
>
> Чтобы избежать этого, вы можете использовать [шаблон POST/redirect/GET](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

---

А вот ещё есть другой ответ на [Зачем нужна решетка в этом запросе и чем первый action отличается от второго?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/862764/204920):

> ... При этом значение фрагмента `#` предохраняет страницу от рефреша.